# Update local database from server in windos phone 7.1

Tags: .net, sql-server, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, windows-phone-7.1

I'm working on push notification service on which i need to take data from server and store on local database in windows phone 7.1 and then retrieve that data from database to windows phone application. 
I've tried almost all tutorial and previous question which is asked in stack overflow related to local database in windows phone 7.1 but I can't implement this task.

I know, I should ask that problem which i faced in particular tutorial but I want to go from starting point again because ,may be my implementation process was wrong.

So. please tell me any tutorial on which someone already implement this task or give me code to store the data from server to database and then retrieve the data from database to windows phone.
I'm using C#.net. If anybody need any additional info please tell me.

Comment: Are you getting the data from push notification service.?

Comment: @user1608857 - yes,but I'm not getting the right way to insert the data in database and retrieve data from database.I've implemented but It's showing error

Comment: Push notifications only notify while app is in background. DataBase operations can be performed only when the app is in foreground.

Comment: @user1608857 - I'm trying to develop an app on which tile notification will come in the front of the phone and when someone click on that,the detail page will open on which all the details of that notification will be store.For that i'm trying to implement firstly a local database on which i'm giving input directly using code for storing in database and then trying to retrieve from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use SQLITE for database operations in Windows Phone applications. Here is a good tutorial which explains [Native Database Programming via Sqlite Client for Windows Phone](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/silverlight/Windows-Phone-7-Native-Database-Programming-via-Sqlite-Client-for-Windows-Phone.aspx)

Alternatively, if you are good at LINQ operations, you can also use [LINQ to SQL](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2011/08/01/windows-phone-7-using-local-database-for-application.aspx)